# Buffer data in Simulink in continuous time

Tags: buffer, simulink

I need to buffer some signals for a **fixed duration** to be **used within the simulation**. The use of buffer block in Simulink requires the frame rate to be known. However, I am using a continuous time solver (with defined maximum step size) so I don't really know how much should I put the buffer size as. There does not seem to be any option wherein a trigger based on time can be used. Can someone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: Use a MATLAB Function Block to write your own buffer that will keep the previous n samples irrespective of when they arrive.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thank you for the reply...so it means the only option is to use a huge buffer size? I say this because with continuous time solver it becomes difficult to estimate how many samples to store...Moreover, if its not too much to ask for, could you provide a small working example as to how to create a buffer...I can take it forward from there...

Answer (score 1):

A simple buffer, made using a MATLAB Function Block, that would always have the most recent element at the top, would be,

```
function y = buffer(x)

% initialize the buffer
y = zeros(100,1);

% Shuffle the elements down
y(2:end) = y(1:end-1);

% add the new element
y(1) = x;
```

Comment: How to initialize the buffer inside a block? Thanks.